# Open an existing Zend project with NetBeans IDE 7.0

Tags: zend-framework, netbeans, netbeans7.0

I have an existing Zend project developed in NetBeans (the project contains all project files for NetBeans)

When I tried to open it for the first time in a new computer with new installed NetBeans 7.0, the NetBeans recognized the project as a regular project and not as a Zend project.

I was looking for a way to set the project as a Zend project after adding it, but didn't find any option how to do this.

(I can create a new Zend project - which lead me to believe this is not Zend configuration problem)

Any Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It turns out, that when you create a zend project, the netbeans creates a the file .zfproject.xml in the project's path.

I copied the file from a new Zend project I managed to create successfully and when I reopened the netbeans it identified the project as a zend project

Answer (score 1):

create a project with the same name of your project and done, it works for me always

Answer (score 0):

"My" Netbeans does detect Zend Framework Projects. I think you have to copy or symlink the Zend library to your project.

Comment: I have the Zend library in the library of the project and as an include path. What version of netbeans do you have?

Comment: 7.0 , do you have the .zfproject.xml inside your project folder?